# In Java program how to export data from database to text file

Tags: java, file, jdbc

I am trying to write a file fetching values from Database using java code.

The `Resultset` values are retrieved from DB & Then writing to a file.I am able to write to File ,But I am not getting the exact value ,instead getting the Junk Value.

Code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");    
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();    

        String n=request.getParameter("device");

                Connection conn = null;  
                PreparedStatement pst = null;  
                ResultSet rs = null;  

                String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";  
                String dbName = "db5";  
                String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
                String userName = "root";  
                String password = "root";  



                 try {  
                        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();  
                        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);  



                    File file = new File("D://Code2.txt");
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);


                    pst = conn.prepareStatement("select latitude,longitude,speed,heading,timeofday,timeofhours,gpssource  from nidgis where nidevid=?");
                    pst.setString(1, n);
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    out.println("<center>");
                    out.println("<h2>LIVE  VEHICLE DATA </h2>");

                    out.println("<table border='1'>");
                    while(rs.next())
                     {
                           out.println("<tr>");

                           out.println("<th>DAYS</th>");
                           out.println("<th>HOURS</th>");
                           out.println("<th>SPEED</th>");
                           out.println("<th>HEADING</th>");
                           out.println("<th>GPSDATA</th>");
                           out.println("</tr>");

                          out.println("<tr>");

                          out.println("<td>"+rs.getInt("timeofday") +"</td>");
                          out.println("<td>"+rs.getInt("timeofhours") +"</td>");
                          out.println("<td>"+rs.getInt("speed") +"</td>");
                          out.println("<td>"+rs.getInt("heading") +"</td>");
                          out.println("<td>"+rs.getInt("gpssource") +"</td>");

                          out.println("</tr>"); 

                          bw.write(rs.getInt("latitude"));  
                          bw.write(rs.getInt("longitude"));


                    }
                    out.println("</table>");

                    out.println("</center>"); 
                    bw.close();                   
                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {  
                    System.out.println(e);  
                } 
                finally 
                {  
                    if (conn != null)
                    {  
                        try {  
                            conn.close();  
                        } catch (SQLException e) {  
                            e.printStackTrace();  
                        }  
                    }  
                    if (pst != null) {  
                        try {  
                            pst.close();  
                        } catch (SQLException e) {  
                            e.printStackTrace();  
                        }  
                    }  
                    if (rs != null) {  
                        try {  
                            rs.close();  
                        } catch (SQLException e)
                        {  
                            e.printStackTrace();  
                        }  
                    }  
                }
```

I am Writing only Latitude & Longitude to File ,Rest Displaying it in a table.For Both data type in DB is DOUBLE.

```
                      bw.write(rs.getInt("latitude"));  
                      bw.write(rs.getInt("longitude"));
```

O/P that I am getting code2.txt is some string values :
M
M

Comment: Try: `bw.write(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("latitude")));`

Comment: I am Getting like this 1277 where 12 is lat 77 is lon,But Iam not getting Full value i.e after decimal (.) my latitude in DB is 12.12212 & longitude 77.23213213 How to fetch this

Comment: That is because those values are `double`s and you are calling `getInt(...)` replace `getInt(...)` with `getDouble(...)`

Comment: offtopic: creating connection on each doPost may be expensive

Comment: How to I add Sap-rate them by , comma 12.56558985
77.8944564613

Answer (score 1):

That's because, your integer is type casted to character as per the [write](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/BufferedWriter.java#BufferedWriter.write%28int%29) api. See this line `cb[nextChar++] = (char) c;`

So int 77 = M character and is what is being written onto file. You could convert your integer to String and write onto file like:

```
bw.write(String.valueOf(rs.getInt("latitude")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to close BufferedWriter and then FileWriter in finally block.

```
bw.close();
fw.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getInt(...)` method returns an `int` value.
You can convert those values to String by using `String.valueOf(rs.getInt(...))`.
Or you can call `rs.getString(...)` to get those values as `String`s from the `ResultSet`

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

- Use `bw.flush()` before `bw.close()`. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#flush%28%29).
- If latitude and longitude are of type double, then why not use `ResultSet#getDouble(...)`?

Also share some more details regarding the original longitude/latitude values and the output that you're getting in the file. This will help is identifying the problem (if any).

Answer (score 0):

You can see this solution:

[exporting sql query result to a csv or excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563376/exporting-sql-query-result-to-a-csv-or-excel/62529402#62529402)

In poperties files set this values:

```
fileExtension=.txt
columSeparator=\t
```