# Export database table to existing excel file

Tags: sql, excel

I've looked already but what I found so far is exporting to a existing excel sheet, what I need is to make a copy of an existing excel template I have and pass my data there. I just need to be pointed in the right way, hope I'm clear enough.

**EDIT**
I have an application working on Java to which I will add this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you ask about SQL Server, you can create 2 step job, one for copying your xls, and in second step using openrowset/insert into your copied excel file. 
Here is Tsql which copies template and also sends an email, and info about xp_cmdshell https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190693.aspx

```
    DECLARE @cmd varchar(512)
    DECLARE @fd varchar(512)
    DECLARE @odbc varchar(128)
    DECLARE @db varchar(128)
    SELECT @fd = 'D:\Reports\Exact\ByWeek' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),                 GETDATE()-8,120)+'_'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),120)+'.xls'
    SELECT @cmd = 'copy D:\Reports\System\shipments_week.xls ' + @fd

    EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL @cmd, NO_OUTPUT

    SET @odbc = 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' 
    SET @db = 'Excel 8.0;Database=' + @fd



    exec('INSERT INTO OPENrowset(''' + @odbc + ''',''' + @db + ''',''SELECT 
  OrderNr,Debtor,SUM_NSHIPPED,SUM_TOTAL,PERC_NSHIPPED,ORDDAT,INVDAT,ORD_SYSCREATED,HIST_LAST_MODIFIED,PT_WZ_SENT
FROM [Shipped$]'')
SELECT * FROM salag_shipmentsbyWeek')

    exec('INSERT INTO OPENrowset(''' + @odbc + ''',''' + @db + ''',''SELECT 
OrderNr,Debtor,SUM_NSHIPPED,SUM_TOTAL,PERC_NSHIPPED,ORDDAT,INVDAT,ORD_SYSCREATED,HIST_LAST_MODIFIED,PT_WZ_SENT
FROM [SB$]'')
SELECT * FROM salag_shipmentsbyWeek WHERE Debtor NOT LIKE ''%CASTORAMA%'' AND Debtor NOT LIKE ''Praktiker%''')


DECLARE @Body VARCHAR(4096)
DECLARE @BodyType VARCHAR(16)
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @f VARCHAR(32)
DECLARE @topic VARCHAR(128)
SELECT @f = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-8,120)+'_'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),120)
SELECT @topic = 'New Report ['+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-8,120)+'_'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),120) + ']'
SELECT @path = '\\appsrv\Reports\Exact\ByWeek' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-8,120)+'_'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),120)+'.xls'
SELECT @Body = 'New Scan Report has been created: '+@f+'   '+ @path
SELECT @BodyType = 'HTMLBody'

exec sp_send_cdosysmail 'Reports Info ','reports@foo ar.com',@topic, @Body, @BodyType
```

Comment: Yes its a SQL server, I'm looking to achieve this in Java. I haven't done this before so don't know if I should download any library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563376/exporting-sql-query-result-to-a-csv-or-excel

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I was looking for using JExcel and it was pretty easy, here I will share my code and hope it helps someone in the future. Sorry its not properly commented yet, I will later post an update.

```
Db_Connect  connection = new Db_Connect();
 conn = connection.connect();



 String originalFile = "C:\\Users\\Geni\\Desktop\\Book1-Template-new.xls";   
 date = date.replace("/", "-");
 SimpleDateFormat myDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

 try{
        Workbook original = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(originalFile));
        WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(date+".xls"), original);

        java.util.Date format = myDate.parse(date);
        java.sql.Date newDate = new java.sql.Date(format.getTime());

        String sql = "SELECT Name, sporecount.* FROM sporesfungi "
        + "INNER JOIN sporecount ON sporesfungi.IDSpore = sporecount.IDSpore"
                + "WHERE Date = ? ORDER BY TraceNum";

        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setDate(1, newDate);
        rs = statement.executeQuery();
        /*stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);*/


        WritableSheet sheet = copy.getSheet(0);
        WritableCell cell;
        String spore;

        while(rs.next()){
            for(int i = 2; i < 64 ;i++){
                cell = sheet.getWritableCell(1,i);
                spore =  cell.getContents();
                if(rs.getString("Name").equals(spore)){
                   Number l1 = new Number(14-rs.getInt("TraceNum"),i,rs.getInt("Amount")) ;
                   sheet.addCell(l1);

                    }

            }
        }


        copy.write();
        copy.close();
        original.close();
    }
    catch (BiffException | IOException e) {
    }
```