# Exporting Excel file from mySQL through Java Servlet

Tags: java, mysql, excel, csv, servlets

Like the title says, I am trying to export an excel file from mySQL through a Java servlet. Below is the code which keeps giving me a 404 Error. Not sure where I'm going wrong here, so any help is appreciated. I got the code from this StackOverflow post: [exporting sql query result to a csv or excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563376/exporting-sql-query-result-to-a-csv-or-excel)

```
package helpers;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFont;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import model.DbConnect;

import java.sql.Statement;

public class ReportsExcelCreator {

     public String downloadExcel(ServletOutputStream out){

        int nRow = 1;
        String strQuery = null;
        Connection con = null;

        HSSFRow row;
        HSSFCell cell;

        try {
             System.out.println("Inside Try");
              HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
              HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Banned Students");

              /* Getting connection here for mysql database */
              Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
              //con = DbConnect.devCredentials();
              con = DriverManager.getConnection
                ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/","Root","");
              System.out.println("Got into server");

              if(con==null)
                    return "Connection Failed";
              /* Database Query */               
              strQuery = "select * from banned";
              Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
              ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(strQuery);

              HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
              HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Excel Sheet");
              HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
              rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("BannedID");
              rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("UserID");
              rowhead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("AdminID");
              rowhead.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue("Ban Start Date");
              rowhead.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue("Ban End Date");
              rowhead.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue("Penalty Count");
              rowhead.createCell((short) 6).setCellValue("Description");
              rowhead.createCell((short) 7).setCellValue("Status"); 

              int index = 1;
              while (rs.next()) {

                      //HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) index);
                      row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(rs.getInt(1));
                      row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(rs.getInt(2));
                      row.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(rs.getInt(3));
                      row.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(rs.getDateTime(4));
                      row.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(rs.getDateTime(5));
                      row.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue(rs.getInt(6));
                      //row.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue(rs.getVarChar(7));
                      row.createCell((short) 6).setCellValue(rs.getInt(8));
                      index++;
              }
             FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("c:\\bannedstudents.xls");
              wb.write(fileOut);
              fileOut.close();
              System.out.println("Data is saved in excel file.");
              rs.close();
              con.close();

      } catch (Exception e) {
}
}
```

Comment: it would be better if you can send the stacktrace

Comment: @AliHelmy There really isn't any information for me to give. It just says 404 Error, and then "The requested resource is not available." No other information than that.

Comment: I don't think that's the code that gives you 404. It's more likely how you access your servlet, or how the servlet uses this code. How do you deploy your webapp, what's the servlet code like, and what URL do you use to access it?

Comment: @NilsH I run it through a button on a JSP page that calls the servlet. 
<form id="downloadBanned" action="/ReportsExcelCreator" method="GET">
            <input  type="submit" value="Download Banned Student List">
    </form>

Comment: You need to provide more information about your deployment and your servlet code. How do you package, deploy and run it, to which context path etc. Please update your question with more information.

Comment: @NilsH Sorry about that. I have been running it locally through Tomcat v7 to see if it works. Nothing fancy, just "Run on Server" on the JSP page, then click the button in hopes it calls the server and downloads the file.

Comment: What's the URL in your browser when you access the JSP?

Comment: @NilsH http://localhost:8080/Reservations/admin/downloadreports.jsp

Comment: In that case, I would assume that the context path of your web application is `/Reservations`. So I would try changing the form action to `/Reservations/ReportsExcelCreator` instead and see if that helps. But it would be a lot easier if you include all the relevant information in your question.