# Insertion of multiple string array into the database

Tags: java, mysql

There are four different array string and i have to insert all data into the database but it is only storing the last string array into the database and the last value of first, second and third array string.

```
public class Scrape {

    private static final String url1 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Scraping_Data";

    private static final String user = "root";

    private static final String password = "root@123";
    private String title="",rating="",price="",url="";

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(String rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
        try
        {
        List<String> ar1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> ar2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> ar3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> ar4 = new ArrayList<String>();
        Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url1, user, password);
        CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("INSERT INTO datascrape(title, price, url, rating) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("-----------").get();
        Elements temp=doc.select("div.productDisplay");
        Scrape s=new Scrape();
        int i=0;
        for(Element itemlist:temp)
        {
            i++;
            s.setTitle(itemlist.select("h4").text());
            s.setPrice(itemlist.select("span.price").text());
            s.setUrl(itemlist.select("a").attr("href"));
            s.setRating(itemlist.select("div.ratings").text());
            ar1.add(s.getTitle());
            ar2.add(s.getPrice());
            ar3.add(s.getUrl());
            ar4.add(s.getRating());

        }
              String[] str1=ar1.toArray(new String[ar1.size()]);
              String[] str2=ar2.toArray(new String[ar2.size()]); 
              String[] str3=ar3.toArray(new String[ar3.size()]);
              String[] str4=ar4.toArray(new String[ar4.size()]);

              for(String s1:str1) { 
                  System.out.println("Title : "+s1);
                  stmt.setString(1, s1);

              }
              for(String s2:str2) {
                  System.out.println("Price : "+s2); 
                  stmt.setString(2,s2);

              } 
              for(String s3:str3) 
              { 
                  System.out.println("URL : "+s3); 
                  stmt.setString(3, s3);

              } 
              for(String s4:str4) { 
                  System.out.println("Rating : "+s4);
                  stmt.setString(4, s4);
                  stmt.execute();

            }



        }
        catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

Only Rating value is inserted into the database. But the last value of title, price and url is stored in  column

Comment: 75% of your code are comments. The remaining code does not interact with the database.

Comment: code has been edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the concept wrong. The whole lists and arrays are unnecessary. Look at this [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/callablestatement.html).

```java
    for(Element itemlist:temp)
    {
        stmt.setString(1, itemlist.select("h4").text());
        stmt.setString(2, itemlist.select("span.price").text());
        stmt.setString(3, itemlist.select("a").attr("href"));
        stmt.setString(4, itemlist.select("div.ratings").text());
        stmt.addBatch();        
    }        
    stmt.execute();
```

Comment: stmt.execute(); will come inside foreach loop. By the way thank you

Comment: Now how to insert all the data from database into csv file. if you can help with this problem i will be very thankful

Comment: For a CSV export [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563376/exporting-sql-query-result-to-a-csv-or-excel)