# Download CSV via PostgreSQL in Vaadin

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, vaadin

I got a Vaadin 14 application, which retrieves data from a PostgreSQL 11 database.
Using Java 8 with 9.4-1202-jdbc42.

I try to achieve a download feature for a table of the database. I created a button with following code snippet. It is working and I can download the example data.

```
StreamResource resource = new StreamResource("foo.csv", () -> new ByteArrayInputStream("foo,foo2,foo3\nboo,boo2,boo3".getBytes()));
Button button = new Button("Click to download");
FileDownloadWrapper buttonWrapper = new FileDownloadWrapper(resource);
buttonWrapper.wrapComponent(button);
add(buttonWrapper);
```

But I want to download data from the PostgreSQL database, not some static input. So I do a "COPY ... TO STDOUT"-request using the CopyManager (org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager).

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
copyManager.copyOut("COPY (" + sql + ") TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER)", outputStream);
```

Edit:
Creating the StreamResource works now, but PostgreSQL doesn't like my sql statement.
Currently this creates an empty csv only with the table headers.

```
CopyOut copiedData = copyManager.copyOut(sqlRequest);
ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(copiedData.readFromCopy());
return new StreamResource("foo.csv", () -> stream);
```

PostgreSQL response for the same sql request in PgAdmin:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM table) TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER)
ERROR:  can't execute COPY TO: use the copy_to() method instead
```

If I replace STDOUT with a filename, it works in PgAdmin

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM table) TO 'D:\test.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);
COPY 63
Query returned successfully in 881 msec.
```

Although I understand that using STDOUT doesn't make much sense in the PgAdmin console, it should work via JDBC, right?

What's wrong with my sql statement? I can't find any good information about copy_to() method.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a CSV file directly out of your database query, you could use the [OpenCSV library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35360379/3608089) to create a CSV file out of your ResultSet.

However, you don't really need the physical file in your file system. There are even some potentially serious downsides to this - files eat up limited disk space, I/O is expensive and there's a potential for accidentally linking one user's file to a different user. `StreamResource` accepts any kind of input stream, so it might be a better idea to keep the whole operation in memory, without an intermediate physical file.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes, the physical file should only be supplied to the user (who presses the download button). I don't want to save it on the server. I guess I'll have to read some more on the general I/O topic.